# Warning to use encapsulated functions

Tags: c++, arrays, oop

I have problem to sort array with objects which are private and they are encapsulated(have getter and setters).I am using my own bubble sort function.

```
void BubbleSort(apvector <int> &num)
{
      int i, j, flag = 1;
      int temp;            
      int numLength = num.length( ); 
      for(i = 1; (i <= numLength) && flag; i++)
     {
          flag = 0;
          for (j=0; j < (numLength -1); j++)
         {
               if (num[j+1] > num[j])      
              { 
                    temp = num[j];            
                    num[j] = num[j+1];
                    num[j+1] = temp;
                    flag = 1;              
               }
          }
     }
```

The problem is there that eclipse IDE sends me warning to use getters and setter in declaration of my class.

Why is better to use getters and setters?

P.S
Sorry for my bad asked question(this was one of my first questions) :)

Comment: I think you don't exactly understand the point of the function signature. It specifies how a function is to be called. This is linked to the mistake you made before: "how to define array in function" - No, you define the array _outside_ `bubbleSort`. And preferably without `new[ ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void bubbleSort(Student* student, int size)
{ [...] }
```

Variable `student` is a pointer to an array.
You must also specific the ***size*** of the array.

To call it:

```
Student* myClass=new Student[5];

bubbleSort(myClass, 5); // Pass the array, and the size of the array both.
```

Comment: ***Show Code***  We require an [**MVCE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Even as a novice, you can ask a question clearly, and post enough code to clearly illustrate what you are having problems with.

Comment: Is it better now ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the said array before sending it as a parameter to the function. Alternatively you can create it inside the function but I think it's not what you want to go for here.

```
Student* students = new Student[5];
```

You should have written this somewhere before calling your function. Then, your function signature will have to turn to the following:

```
void bubbleSort(Student* student)
```

A logical thing to do would be to use a `std::vector` here though, it's much better than the method you're going for. See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector